# Set backgroundColor and Badge for Tabnavigator in React-Navigation

Tags: react-native, badge, tabnavigator, react-navigation

In React-Native with React-Navigation I have a Tabnavigator like so:

```
const testScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
    Tab1: { screen: Tab1Screen },
    Tab2: { screen: Tab2Screen },
    Tab3: { screen: Tab3Screen },
});
testScreenNavigator.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'MY TITLE',
    header: {
        titleStyle:{
        },
        style:{
// how to set the options?
        },
    }  
}
```

Now I want to do 2 things:

1. Set the backgroundColor: 'red' of the Tabs in Android (not iOS bottom tabs)
2. Have a badge next to Tab1: e.g.

### Tab1 (2)  |   Tab2   |    Tab3

Regards

Comment: Thx @Kishan: I will open a new question for the badge.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- Set the backgroundColor for Header and Tab

To set background color for Header use `navigationOptions` and to set background color for Tab use `tabBarOptions`. See below code

```
const testScreenNavigator = TabNavigator ({
  Tab1: { screen: RecentChatsScreen },
  Tab2: { screen: AllContactsScreen },
  Tab3: { screen: AllContactsScreen}
}, {
  tabBarOptions : {
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#42a5f5',
    }
  }
});

testScreenNavigator.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'MY TITLE',
  header: {
    style: {
      backgroundColor: '#42a5f5',
    }
  },
};
```

below is output

[image]